# Incrementing value by one over a lot of rows

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I have a script to cycle over 10M records, it's very slow and it goes like this:
I first get a block of 1000 results in an array similar to this:

```
$matches[] = array('quality_rank'=>46732, 'db_id'=>5532);
$matches[] = array('quality_rank'=>12324, 'db_id'=>1234);
$matches[] = array('quality_rank'=>45235, 'db_id'=>8345);
$matches[] = array('quality_rank'=>75543, 'db_id'=>2562);
```

I then cycle through them one by one and update the record

```
$mult = count($matches)*2;
foreach($matches as $m)
{
    $rank++;
    $score = (($m[quality_rank] + $rank)/($mult))*100;
    $s = "UPDATE `packages_sorted` SET 
    `price_rank` = '".$rank."', 
    `deal_score` = '".$score."' 
    WHERE `db_id` = '".$m[db_id]."' LIMIT 1";
}
```

It seems like this is a very slow way of doing it but I can't find another way to increment the field `price_rank` by one each time. Can anyone suggest a better method.

Note: Although I wouldn't usually store this kind of value in a database I really do need on this occasion for comparison search queries later on in the project.

Any help would be kindly appreciated :)

Comment: "It seems like this is a very slow way of doing it". Doing what? It isn't really clear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry if it's unclear. It's slow because I need to update every record (10,000,000 of them) individually.

Comment: What is it you are trying to increment? Is it quality_rank?

Comment: `price_rank` is the field I need to increment and I use $rank++ for each record to achieve this.

Comment: Andy is this a database that needs updating constantly with the new values for every row? Is there no way to be selective about which ones you update?

Comment: This update is required once daily (when the 10M records are imported into a truncated table). While there are 10M records in the database, between 5,000 to 100,000 records get updated at a time (each with varying criteria).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL follows.

```
SET @rank = 0;
SET @mult = [your code to get # of matches];

UPDATE `packages_sorted` 
SET
    `price_rank` = @rank:=@rank+1,
    `deal_score` = (`quality_rank` + @rank) / (@mult) * 100
ORDER BY [ your code to get correct order of ranking here ];
```

Comment: Oohh! That looks good!
Can I run the `SET` commands through PHP?

Comment: Thank you very much. For some reason I thought that by sending the queries one at a time it would forget the `SET` statements. It does of course work and it's a LOT faster now thanks :) Great tip and I'll be using it again and again!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry maybe I don't know what you are trying to do but you can just increment a value in pure sql if you do:

```
 UPDATE packages_sorted SET price_rank = (price_rank + 1 ) WHERE ...
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot to mention. The array of matches are ordered based on another field `price` when they are selected from the database. There are also multiple fields used to select what constitutes a match. Lastly, the initial `price_rank` will have no bearing of what the new `price_rank` value needs to be so I can't increment them.